# Scala filter elements in Seq/Array between separators

Tags: arrays, scala, list, filter

I have an array such as :

````
val array = Array("Hello", "```", "blabla", "anything", "filler", "```", "another filler")
````

The `filter` method is only on each element of the array or Seq

````
array.filter(s => !s.startsWith("```"))
> Array(Hello, blabla, anything, filler, another filler)
````

I want to remove anything between the separators ```` "```" ````. The end result will be

```
Array("Hello", "another filler")
```

The problem is similar to [Bracket coding task solved by a Stack](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/brackets/). 
How could you accomplish this in pure FP ?

**Further**

There are 2 sections delimited by the separator ```` "```" ````.

Note: the separator is not equal but starts with ```` "```" ```` . There is one ```` "```scala" ````

````
val input = Array("Hello", "```", "blabla1", "```", "blabla2", "```scala","blabla3", "filler", "```", "blabla4")

filteredOutput =  Array("Hello", "blabla2", "blabla4")
````

PS : Maybe you figured out, the solution filters out the code comment from a markdown file.

Comment: What if you have an odd number of `"```"`? Keep the last?

Comment: Yes, keep the last. 
For odd number of `"```"` , the last separator "```" will be in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should meet your updated requirements.

````
def condense(ss: Seq[String], delimiter: String): Seq[String] = {
  val start = ss.indexWhere(_.startsWith(delimiter))
  val stop  = ss.indexWhere(_.startsWith(delimiter), start + 1)
  if (stop < 0) ss
  else condense(ss.patch(start, Seq(), stop-start+1), delimiter)
}

condense(input, "```")  // res0: Array[String] = Array(Hello, blabla2, blabla4)
````

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is necessarily the best way, but one way I came up with is to fold it:

````
val (filteredOutput: Array[String], _) =
  input.foldLeft((Array[String](), true)) {
    case ((output: Array[String], include: Boolean), sep) if sep.startsWith("```") => (output, !include)
    case ((output: Array[String], true), next: String) => (output :+ next, true)
    case ((output: Array[String], false), _) => (output, false)
  }
````

Here's an updated version that should handle your updated requirement with regards to odd number of separators:

````
val filteredOutput = {
  val (workingOutput: Array[String], _, discard: List[String]) =
    input.foldLeft((Array[String](), true, List[String]())) {
      case ((output: Array[String], include: Boolean, _), sep) if sep.startsWith("```") =>
        (output, !include, if (include) List(sep) else Nil)

      case ((output: Array[String], true, _), next: String) =>
        (output :+ next, true, Nil)
      case ((output: Array[String], false, discard: List[String]), next: String) =>
        (output, false, next :: discard)
    }
  workingOutput ++ discard.reverse
}
````

Comment: I made a small edit in the Further section. The separator starts by "```" , it is not equal to .

Comment: I've updated it to reflect that separators start with "```". However, it doesn't meet your new requirement for odd number of separators.

Comment: Nice one. At least, it is not recursive like the 2 other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Another version, avoiding the use of indices:

````
val input = Array("Hello", "```", "blabla1", "```",
                  "blabla2", "```scala", "blabla3", "filler", "```", "blabla4")

def condense(xs: Array[String], acc: Array[String] = Array()): Array[String] = {
  if (xs.isEmpty) acc
  else {
    val (before, after) = xs.span(!_.startsWith("```"))
    val remaining = after.drop(1).dropWhile(!_.startsWith("```"))
    if (remaining.isEmpty) // unclosed commment
      acc ++ xs
    else condense(remaining.drop(1), acc ++ before)
  }
} 

condense(input) //> res0: Array[String] = Array(Hello, blabla2, blabla4)
````

Comment: Nice, but you missed the additional requirement (mentioned in the question's comments):  "For odd number of `"```"` , the last separator `"```"` will be in the output."

Comment: Blech. Yes, missed that comment. Fixed.